# Python ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

When I run the following code:

```
if df.loc[df['state_code'].isin(['12','09'])]:
```

It gives this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
>       Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide your dataframe? I suspect that `isin` might return `True` on some columns but `False` on other columns.

Comment: This is not a pure python exception. Please tell us about your environment. And it would be helpful to describe what df is.

Answer (score 6):

The issue tells you that the `Series` returned by your operation holds no intrinsic truth value. Indeed, the operation will always return something and you have to chose what you actually want:

- if **any** of the returned values is true, meaning there exists an element in `df` which is in `['12','09']`
- if **all** of the returned values are true, meaning all elements in `df` are in `['12','09']`
- if the returned `Series` contains any element, meaning not `empty`

So:

```
if not df.loc[df['state_code'].isin(['12','09'])].empty:
```

or

```
if df.loc[df['state_code'].isin(['12','09'])].any():
```

or

```
if df.loc[df['state_code'].isin(['12','09'])].all():
```

Check out the [**documentation**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.html)

For more help, provide a minimal working example of your code

Comment: Thanks, if df.loc[df['state_code'].isin(['12','09'])].any(): did not work for me but  if not df.loc[df['state_code'].isin(['12','09'])].empty: worked perfectly.